# Настройка авторизации через GitLab

Tags: django, gitlab

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос.

Разворачиваю локально ReadTheDocs у себя на компьютере. Все поставилось и работает.

В ReadTheDosc есть функция подключение аккаунтов: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно настроить подключение для гитлаба. Но выползает ошибка:

```
 DoesNotExist at /accounts/gitlab/login/
 SocialApp matching query does not exist.
```

Нужно объявить подключение в Django.

Захожу в настройки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал долго ID и секретный ключ от Gitlaba, но так и не нашел.

Если не сложно, подскажите где посмотреть данную информацию.

Ps делаю по примеру для фейсбука: [видос](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yqKNQ3ogKQ&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: А у вас и гитлаб свой, локальный?

Comment: @NickVolynkin нет. Но я думаю, это ведь сможет все проработать, если ReadTheDocs будет развернуть локально.

Comment: Должно работать. Где-то есть сервер readthedocs.org, и на нём RTD тоже развёрнут локально, точно как у вас.

Comment: Я знаю только одного человека, к которому я бы сам с этим вопросом пошёл — это Eric Holscher, один из авторов RTD. Его можно найти в [слаке Write the Docs](http://www.writethedocs.org/slack/), @ericholscher. Но наверняка не только он знает ответ.

Comment: Предлагаю вам задать вопрос на en.SO. Если за день никто не ответит — пишите Эрику со ссылкой на вопрос, он парень дружелюбный. Помочь вам с переводом вопроса на английский?

Comment: Не понял, на что мне глянуть?

Comment: @NickVolynkin не так прочел. Уже удалил комментарий. Извиняюсь. А вот перевести вопрос, это будет отлично. И с ресурсом en.SO пока что ни разу не работал,сейчас там зададим вопрос.
А так спасибо. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока что пришел к такому, что нужно зайти в настройки аккаунта на GitLab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имя вводим какое вам угодно, URL указываем ваш. В моем случае это

http://127.0.0.1:8000/

После чего выбираем права доступа, жмем сохранить.

Нам выскакивает такой окошко, где будет указан ID и секретный ключ.
(Обрезал в целях безопасности)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но осталась проблема, что не идет авторизация, выдает ошибку так же.
 Если поставить обращение к example.com в категории сайт: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То выдает следующее: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это уже ближе к истине.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того какой гитлаб (публичный или локалный) надо зайти в профиль или в Admin-панель, затем в Applications.

Ставим все галки (хотя возможно все и не нужно).
Созданные ID и ключ вставляем в соответствующие поля `http://[readthedocs.domain.name]/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/add/`.

Чтобы не появлялось `Redirect URI included is not valid.`, нужно в *Redirect URI* вставлять `http://[readthedocs.domain.name]/accounts/gitlab/login/callback/`.

Как вы понимаете, то для github и других сервисов всё в принципе аналогично.